# Multiple drop down menus

Tags: google-fusion-tables

How would I create a custom map that has multiple drop down menus? In essence, the model I'm after is this map:

http://www.lmcc.net/about/culture_map

I want to separate places into different categories and have them be accessible through different drop down menus. I do also like the feature of the check box showing all the places in that category.

Is this something I would have to create through Fusion tables? Or is there another way? Any sort of help on how to create a map like this would be great

Thanks!

Comment: That map is a straight Google Maps API v2 map using XML data.

Comment: [An example from the Fusion Tables Layer documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/adv_fusiontables) (although it does leave something to be desire with dependencies between the dropdowns).